# Why list of HttpPostedFileBase is null when uploading multiple files?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

On the client side, I have the following code:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("UploadStatistics")" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h4>Upload Statistics Excel file(s)</h4>
<p>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple/>
</p>

<input type="submit" onclick="ClearDirtyFlag();" />
```

So the user can select multiple files to upload.

On the server-side I have this code:

```
public ViewResult UploadStatistics(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    //the issue is that the files parameter comes null...
}
```

**Note**: If I don't expect a **list of HttpPostedFileBase** objects (but just only a **HttpPostedFileBase** parameter), the code works just fine...

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here ?

Best regards.

Comment: `name="file"` does not match your parameter name (plural). Change it to `name="files"` (or the parameter to `List<HttpPostedFileBase> file`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, it is working perfectly. if you want, please write this as an answer so I can accept it, maybe it will help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input has `name="file"` but the parameter in your POST method is named `files` - they do not match. Change the input to

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="file" multiple/>
```

or better, have a view model with a property

```
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
```

and strongly bind to your model using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file" })
```

which gives you the added benefit of being able to apply validation attributes and get client and server side validation